# Running Batch File on Multiple text Files

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple batch file that deletes the first 26 lines of a text file specified by the batch file on the desktop.

```
more +26 "data (1).txt" >"data (1).txt.new"

move /y "data (1).txt.new" "data (1).txt"
```

What I want to be able to do is run this on multiple text files with similar naming conventions such as `data (1).txt`, `data (2).txt`, `data (3).txt`, with the number of files fluctuating week to week.

I would also like for the program to be able to search for the file in its actual location and not have to bring the text files to the desktop to be able to run it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried to wild card the numbers but that doesn't seem to work. To be honest I'm extremely new to all of this. This is the first one I made this morning by searching around the internet to even get it created. I hope I'm not off base by asking for help outright like this.

Comment: Asking for help is what this site is for, it's just that "do this for me" is generally looked down upon. "What am I doing wrong here," on the other hand, is highly encouraged.

Comment: Also, are the files actually called "data (1).txt" "data (2).txt" etc? Leaving out information will almost always lead to a delay in getting the answer.

Comment: Could you point me in a direction that I could learn how to do the above task?

Comment: If the files actually look like "data (number).txt", I'd recommend using `for /L` to iterate the numbers and `if exist` in case the numbers skip around for some reason. The documentation provided by `for /?` and `if /?` should help, and ss64.com has examples that should prove useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\one"
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*(*).txt") DO (
 ECHO(MORE +26 "%%a" GTR "%%a.new"
 ECHO(MOVE /y "%%a.new" "%%a"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MORE/MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` and `ECHO(MORE` to `MORE` to actually process the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`) on the `MOVE` and change `GTR` to `>` on the `MORE`.

This assumes you know which directory contains the files and that the files to be processed conform to the pattern `*(*).txt`. If the requirement is actually for `data(*).txt` then change `*(*)` to that.